# How to control partition size in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have a requirement to load data from an Hive table using Spark SQL `HiveContext` and load into HDFS. By default, the `DataFrame` from SQL output is having 2 partitions. To get more parallelism i need more partitions out of the SQL. There is no overloaded method in `HiveContex`t to take number of partitions parameter.

Repartitioning of the RDD causes shuffling and results in more processing time.

>

```
val result = sqlContext.sql("select * from bt_st_ent")
```

Has the log output of:

```
Starting task 0.0 in stage 131.0 (TID 297, aster1.com, partition 0,NODE_LOCAL, 2203 bytes)
Starting task 1.0 in stage 131.0 (TID 298, aster1.com, partition 1,NODE_LOCAL, 2204 bytes)
```

I would like to know is there any way to increase the partitions size of the SQL output.

Answer (score 21):

**Spark < 2.0**:

You can use Hadoop configuration options:

- `mapred.min.split.size`.
- `mapred.max.split.size`

as well as HDFS block size to control partition size for **filesystem based** formats*.

```scala
val minSplit: Int = ???
val maxSplit: Int = ???

sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("mapred.min.split.size", minSplit)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("mapred.max.split.size", maxSplit)
```

**Spark 2.0+**:

You can use `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` configuration:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", maxSplit)
```

In both cases these values may not be in use by a specific data source API so you should always check documentation / implementation details of the format you use.

---

* Other input formats can use different settings. See for example

- [Partitioning in spark while reading from RDBMS via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43150694/6910411)
- [Difference between mapreduce split and spark paritition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39651842/6910411)

Furthermore `Datasets` created from `RDDs` will inherit partition layout from their parents.

Similarly bucketed tables will use bucket layout defined in the metastore with 1:1 relationship between bucket and `Dataset` partition.

Answer (score 5):

A very common and painful problem. You should look for a key which distributes the data in uniform partitions. The you can use the `DISTRIBUTE BY` and `CLUSTER BY` operators to tell spark to group rows in a partition. This will incur some overhead on the query itself. But will result in evenly sized partitions. [Deepsense](http://deepsense.io/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/) has a very good tutorial on this.

Comment: For those landing here from google: Deepsense seems to have changed their top-level domain, so the link from above is outdated. 
Post is now at https://deepsense.ai/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/

Comment: I was trying to implement distribute/cluster on a iceberg table while reading but partitions created on dataframe are same in number and size. I am using primary key to distribute the data.

Answer (score 3):

If your SQL performs a shuffle (for example it has a join, or some sort of group by), you can set the number of partitions by setting the 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' property

```
 sqlContext.setConf( "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 64)
```

Following up on what Fokko suggests, you could use a random variable to cluster by.

```
val result = sqlContext.sql("""
   select * from (
     select *,random(64) as rand_part from bt_st_ent
   ) cluster by rand_part""")
```