# How-to spread the job so as to not run out of memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run some spark jobs, but routinely the executors run out of memory:

```
17/02/06 19:12:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 476.3 (TID 133250, 10.0.0.10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1486378087852_0006_01_000019 on host: 10.0.0.10. Exit status: 52. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1486378087852_0006_01_000019
Exit code: 52
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=52:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:933)
```

Since I've already set `spark.executor.memory=20480m`, I feel that the job shouldn't really need more RAM to work, so the other option I see is to increase the number of partitions.

I've tried:

```
>>> sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", u"2001")
>>> sqlContext.getConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
u'2001'
```

and

```
>>> all_users.repartition(2001)
```

however when I start a job I still see the default 200 partitions:

```
>>> all_users.repartition(2001).show()
[Stage 526:(0 + 30) / 200][Stage 527:>(0 + 0) / 126][Stage 528:>(0 + 0) / 128]0]
```

I'm using PySpark 2.0.2 on Azure HDInsight. Can anyone point what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

According to the answer below I tried:

```
sqlContext.setConf('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', 2001)
```

at the start but it didn't work. However, this worked:

```
sqlContext.setConf('spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes', 100000000)
```

all_users is an sql dataframe. A specific example would be:

```
all_users = sqlContext.table('RoamPositions')\ 
    .withColumn('prev_district_id', F.lag('district_id', 1).over(user_window))\ 
    .withColumn('prev_district_name', F.lag('district_name', 1).over(user_window))\
    .filter('prev_district_id IS NOT NULL AND prev_district_id != district_id')\
    .select('timetag', 'imsi', 'prev_district_id', 'prev_district_name', 'district_id', 'district_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks like you read data from an external source and use window functions before you call `repartition`. Window functions:

- Repartition data to a single partition if there is no `partitionBy` clause provided.
- Use standard shuffle mechanism if you provide `partitionBy` clause.

The latter one seems to be the case here. Since default value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partition` is 200 your data will be shuffled into 200 partitions before it is repartitioned. If you want 2001 all the way you should set it **before** loading the data

```py
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", u"2001")

all_users = ...
```

Also `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` doesn't affect the number of initial partitions. These can be controlled using other properties: [How to increase partitions of the sql result from HiveContext in spark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38249624/6910411)