# Why don't Sizes of File Splits decrease as I repartition data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I'm running a Spark batch job that processes a large (51G) xml file using the [`spark-xml` datasource](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml). I'm running locally on my machine.

I want to use all my cores (8) but I want to keep each task size small so that the total RAM used by all tasks does not grow more than what I have available.

So I've used `repartition` like this:

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.read
  .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .option("rowTag", "row")
  .load(s"$pathToInputXML")
  .repartition(30)
```

So I thought that each task would handle about (51GB / 30 partitions / 8
 cores) == 212MB per task.

The thing is, it looks like each task is only 33MB long, as you can see by the output:

```
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:0+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:134217728+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:33554432+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:234881024+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:201326592+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:100663296+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:167772160+33554432
17/04/28 19:40:02 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/felipe/SAMSUNG/StackHeavy/Posts.xml:67108864+33554432
```

Could anyone explain this to me? Why doesn't the size of the file split change as I change the number of partitions?

Comment: Try `coalesce(30)` instead of `repartition(30)`. `repartition` will create a shuffle.

Comment: By the way, I think input splits will always same. You should check the task number.

Comment: @zsxwing I see. please add a answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the size of the file split change as I change the number of partitions?

Because `repartitioning` doesn't affect input splits. Your code shuffles the data after it has been loaded into Spark.

If you're want to modify number of input split you [should adjust `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38249624/6910411) parameter.