# How to force Spark Dataframe to be split across all the worker nodes?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to create a small dataframe with just 10 rows. And I want to force this dataframe to be distributed to two worker nodes. My cluster has only two worker nodes. How do I do that?

Currently, whenever I create such a small dataframe, it gets persisted in only one worker node.

I know, Spark is build for Big Data and this question does not make much sense. However, conceptually, I just wanted to know if at all it is feasible or possible to enforce the Spark dataframe to be split across all the worker nodes (given a very small dataframe with 10-50 rows only).

Or, it is completely impossible and we have to rely upon the Spark master for this dataframe distribution?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553005/spark-dataframe-not-distributed

Comment: did you find a way ?

Comment: nope. Apparently, we don't have any control here. It is the Spark master's task scheduler who has this control and he thinks that it does not make sense to split such a small data frame to different machines. That's overkill and extra processing.