# Did Spark 2.3 change the way it process small files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-2.0

I just started to play with Spark 2+ (2.3 version) and I observed something strange when looking at Spark UI.
I have a list of directories in HDFS cluster containing in total 24000 small files.

When I want to run a Spark action on them, Spark 1.5 generates an individual task for each input file, as I was used until now. I know that each HDFS block (in my case one small file is one block) generate one partition in Spark and each partition is processed by an individual task.

[image: Spark 1.5 UI screenshot]

Also, the command `my_dataframe.rdd.getNumPartitions()` outputs 24000.

Now about Spark 2.3
On the same input, command `my_dataframe.rdd.getNumPartitions()` outputs 1089. The Spark UI also generate 1089 tasks for my Spark action. You can see also that the number of generated jobs is bigger in spark 2.3 then 1.5

[image: Spark 2.3 UI screenshot]

The code is the same for both Spark versions (I needed to change a little the dataframe, paths and column names, because it's code from work):

```py
%pyspark
dataframe = sqlContext.\
                read.\
                parquet(path_to_my_files)
dataframe.rdd.getNumPartitions()
dataframe.\
    where((col("col1") == 21379051) & (col("col2") == 2281643649) & (col("col3") == 229939942)).\
    select("col1", "col2", "col3").\
    show(100, False)
```

Here is the physical plan generated by

```
dataframe.where(...).select(...).explain(True)
```

```
Spark 1.5
== Physical Plan ==
Filter (((col1 = 21379051) && (col2 = 2281643649)) && (col3 = 229939942))
 Scan ParquetRelation[hdfs://cluster1ns/path_to_file][col1#27,col2#29L,col3#30L]
Code Generation: true

Spark 2.3
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [col1#0, col2#2L, col3#3L]
+- *(1) Filter (((isnotnull(col1#0) && (col1#0 = 21383478)) && (col2 = 2281643641)) && (col3 = 229979603))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [col1,col2,col3] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://cluster1ns/path_to_file..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(col1)], ReadSchema: struct<col1:bigint,col2:bigint,col3:bigint>....
```

Above jobs was generated from zeppelin using pyspark.
Is there anyone else who met this situation with spark 2.3 ?
I do have to say that I like the new way to process multiple small files, but I would like also to have knowledge about possible internal Spark changes.

I searched on internet, newest book "Spark the definitive guide" but didn't find any information about a new way of Spark to generate the physical plan for jobs.

If you have any links or information, would be interesting to read.
Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide job code?

Comment: Hi @addmeaning, I added the code in the post context. Thanks !

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward. Can you try to run `dataframe.explain(True)` for both versions of spark, to test if code translates to a different set of operations?

Comment: Nice idea, I run the explain(True) on the resulted dataframe from select.
I added the physical plan (again with some code obfuscation)

Comment: 2.x [doesn't use Hadoop configuration to compute splits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40703599/6910411). So this accounts for the number of partitions.

Comment: Thanks @user6910411, I could be the explanation. I have to check that. But seems to be more posts related to "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes" config properties on internet.

Answer (score -2):

From 
[Spark 2.3 configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

|spark.files.maxPartitionBytes| 134217728 (128 MB)  | The maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files.