# How to define partitions to Dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, data-partitioning, apache-spark-1.6

Suppose I read a parquet file as a Dataframe in pyspark, how can I specify how many partitions it must be?

I read the parquet file like this -

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('parquet').load('/path/to/file')
```

How may I specify the number of partitions to be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change partition size in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249624/how-to-change-partition-size-in-spark-sql)

Comment: @user9613318 Its not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249624/how-to-change-partition-size-in-spark-sql) about _partition size_.