# Spark MapPartition does not do any things on the RDD in python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe with four columns. I want to do some operations on each group of its rows. In fact, I have to do grouping based on the first column.
The Dataframe is like this:

```
+-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
|Account|nature|value|           time|repeated|
+-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
|      a|     1|   50|10:05:37:293084| false  |
|      a|     1|   50|10:06:46:806510| false  |
|      a|     0|   50|11:19:42:951479| false  |
|      a|     1|   40|19:14:50:479055| false  |
|      a|     0|   50|16:56:17:251624| false  |
|      a|     1|   40|16:33:12:133861| false  |
|      a|     1|   20|17:33:01:385710| false  |
|      b|     0|   30|12:54:49:483725| false  |
|      b|     0|   40|19:23:25:845489| false  |
|      b|     1|   30|10:58:02:276576| false  |
|      b|     1|   40|12:18:27:161290| false  |
|      b|     0|   50|12:01:50:698592| false  |
|      b|     0|   50|08:45:53:894441| false  |
|      b|     0|   40|17:36:55:827330| false  |
|      b|     1|   50|17:18:41:728486| false  |
+-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
```

I want to compare nature column of one row to other rows with the same Account and value,I should look forward, and add new column named Repeated. The new column get true for both rows, if nature changed, from 1 to 0 or vise versa. The result must be like this:

```
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
 |Account|nature|value|           time|Repeated|
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
 |      a|     1|   50|10:05:37:293084|   true |
 |      a|     1|   50|10:06:46:806510|    true|
 |      a|     0|   50|11:19:42:951479|   true |
 |      a|     0|   50|16:56:17:251624|   true |
 |      b|     0|   50|08:45:53:894441|   true |
 |      b|     0|   50|12:01:50:698592|   false|
 |      b|     1|   50|17:18:41:728486|   true |
 |      a|     1|   40|16:33:12:133861|   false|
 |      a|     1|   40|19:14:50:479055|   false|
 |      b|     1|   40|12:18:27:161290|    true|
 |      b|     0|   40|17:36:55:827330|   true |
 |      b|     0|   40|19:23:25:845489|   false|
 |      b|     1|   30|10:58:02:276576|    true|
 |      b|     0|   30|12:54:49:483725|   true |
 |      a|     1|   20|17:33:01:385710|   false|
 +-------+------+-----+---------------+--------+
```

Since, I have to iterate over each group of "Account,value", therefore,I cannot use Window Functions like **lead()** or **lag()**. So, I choose to use **Mappartitions**. I wrote my function to call it for each Partition.

The function is this:

```
def check(part):
arr = []
print('part:',part)
for x in part:
    arr.append(tuple(x))
for i in arr:
     list_i = list(i)
     index_i = arr.index(i)
     i_value = list_i[1]
     i_value2 = list_i[3]
     if (i_value2 == True):
         continue
     else:
         for j in arr[(arr.index(i) + 1):]:
            list_j = list(j)
            index_j = arr.index(j)
            j_value = list_j[1]
            j_value2 = list_j[3]
            if (i_value!=j_value) & (j_value2==False):
                list_j[3] = True
                arr[index_j] = tuple(list_j)
                list_i[3] = True
                arr[index_i] = tuple(list_i)
                break
print('arr:',arr)
return iter(arr)
```

Then:

```
df.repartition('Account','value').rdd.mapPartitions(check).toDF(['Account','nature','value','time','repeated']).count()
```

The function is not finished and I receive this output:

```
part: <itertools.chain object at 0x000002452FC9D460>
arr: []
part: <itertools.chain object at 0x0000017D4B91D460>
arr: []
...
```

Would you please guide me what is wrong with my code?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Too vague for me

Comment: Dear @thebluephantom thank you for seeing the question. Would you please guide me that using **mappartition** in this way is right or not? ```df.repartition('Account','value').rdd.mapPartitions(check).toDF(['Account','nature','value','time','repeated']).count()```

Comment: You do not need mapPartitions as far as I can see. If you know ordering within an account should be possible to do what you want.

Comment: In fact, I have 20 partitions in my program. Information of the same "Accounts" is in the same partition. And, "check" function should be run for each group account. So, I have to use **mappartition**.

Comment: @thebluephantom, would you please explain more? about: **you know ordering within an account should be possible to do what you want**.

Comment: If u want to do things the hard way, fine. I saw another answer to a question of youts matt andruff that gives context. I want nothing, you want something btw.

Comment: @thebluephantom, I really want to choose the simple way. About the matt andruff's suggestion, would you please tell me if I can solve the problem with **window** function? I am a newbie in this subject.

Comment: Look ahead 1? Each row part of 2 compares.

Comment: @thebluephantom, sorry I don't understand what you mean. Would you please explain more?

Comment: How can 1st row be true?

Comment: @thebluephantom, if the 1st row after that row has opposite value  in "nature" column.

Comment: I cannot read that from description, but maybe why I see [3]. Anyway, rehash the question as it is poorly explained.