# No of partitions set in the program is not matching with the no of partitions showing in spark web ui

Tags: java, apache-spark

The partitions created for the below word count program is 10, but as per my understanding if we set master("local[2]") while creating a sparksession object means it will run locally with 2 cores i.e 2 partitions

Can someone help me why my spark code is creating 10 partitions instead of creating 2.

CODE :

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaWordCount").master("local[2]").getOrCreate();

    JavaRDD<String> lines = spark.read().textFile(args[0]).javaRDD();

    JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s)).iterator());

    JavaPairRDD<String, Double> pairRDD = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1.0));
```

ScreenShort of Spark Web UI :

[image]

Comment: There could just as easily be 5 tasks being done by each core... Those aren't the only values determining the stages https://qubole.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217111026-Reference-Relationship-between-Partitions-Tasks-Cores

Answer (score 0):

> it will run locally with 2 cores i.e 2 partitions

It doesn't mean that at all. It means Spark can use at most 2 threads for data processing. But with rare exceptions (like `parallelize`) this has nothing to do with the number of partitions used.

In such simple pipeline the number of partitions will depend on the value of [`spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249624/how-to-change-partition-size-in-spark-sql).